# make Scrollview unscrollable android studio

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

i have three horizontal scrollviews in one activity:

```
HorizontalScrollView eventScroll;
HorizontalScrollView heavenScroll;
HorizontalScrollView bottomScroll;
```

i want the user to only be able to use eventScroll and the two others should set their x position depending what x position eventScroll has like this:

```
    eventScroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollX = eventScroll.getScrollX();

            heavenScroll.setScrollX(scrollX / 5);
            bottomScroll.setScrollX(scrollX * 3);


        }
    });
```

now my problem is the user can still scroll on the other scrollviews for a sec or so before the x position reset itself to correct value, so i would like to disable the other scrollviews for the user but i still want the mot be able to change ScrollX value.

Comment: `make Scrollview unscrollable` What's the use for an unscrollable scrollable?! Don't use any ScrollView at all, if you don't need it.

Comment: Hmm i am trying to create a 3d effect with different layers  1 top layer 1 mid layer and 1 botom layer. And the user is supposed to scroll on the mid layer and then top and bottom should auto scroll at different speeds for etxample the sky should move closer than the ground i get this to work its just i want to disable top and bot layer for the user

Comment: But the unscrollable View can be a fixed one. Or simply a background image painted onto the root container.

Comment: Bit if the sky is not a scrollview how can i then get the image to "scroll" with the middle layer?

Comment: So, you want it **scrollable**? Why don't you change the misleading title, then? `make Scrollview unscrollable ...`

Comment: i don't want the user to be able to scroll it just scrolling it via java code i guess i change the title to that...

Comment: try intercepting the scrollview's touch events. it seems that you are trying to implement a parallax effect - I've seen this done with texture offsets all the time, but never using separate views. good luck.

Comment: i solved the problem by the answer below =)! thx anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    heavenScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```